# Reading CSV input file by field name instead of position in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a CSV file with four fields:

```
FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, FIELD_D
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
```

I also created a transformation in PDI that has a Read CSV Input file step and a following step that inserts the values in a database table.

This works fine, however I may get other combinations in the input file (without notice), such as:

```
FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_D
1, 2, 4
5, 6, 8
```

I was assuming that PDI was going to be intelligent enough to map the fields by name, and send to the next step FIELD_A, FIELD_B, and so on, depending on the position of the column header. Instead, it takes the first three fields in the file and maps them to the first three fields in the step. As a result, I get in FIELD_C the values of FIELD_D.

Is there a way to have the transformation map by field name instead of position? I cannot change the transformation every time an input field is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have many way to do this. Use 'Select Values' step before insert to DB is the simple way. You can find the sample transformation from  [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IR7CHy3BlXS-IVUxsBDXehlzHNKcDlyA?usp=sharing). Where in the 'CSV file input', you can first call file with 4 field and after that you can call file with 3 field for testing.
Let me know if its ok or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My issue is in the 'CSV file input' step, what do you mean by "call file with 4 fields" ? Note that in the real scenario I have 200 fields.

Comment: Yes, at first you need to prepare 'CSV file input' step with the file (which has maximum fields 200) and complete the 'Select Values' step. After that, if you found the csv file with less then 200 field than others field value will return as null in the 'select values' step automatically. And matching filed name will return expected values.

Comment: or you can share your transformation you have try so far.

Comment: [this is what I have so far](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au4Vkx6gmEf-5Ev34Y2OsoK7J7qV?e=kTA44j), a step that reads the csv file, and a step that writes the fields in the database. The fields in the file may come in any order, and sometimes some fields will be missing. How do I add the 'Selected Values' step?

Comment: you can find the updated transformation from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IR7CHy3BlXS-IVUxsBDXehlzHNKcDlyA?usp=sharing        I have tested and found its working.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. I have a column named X in position 60 in my Read CSV Input step, and in the CSV file is column 63. The only thing that matches is the column name, not the position. Instead of taking the value from column in position 63 it took the values from position 60.

Comment: I know i can help you. I think there have something messing between our requirement understanding. You can send me a document with your requirement in brief. and also send 2 sample csv file with your problem. [Then if require we will use metadata injection as well]

Answer (score 2):

You have also the option of injecting metadata to the transformation to read the CSV file and insert in the table.
You first create a transformation to read which columns are present in the CSV file (reading only the first line of the CSV with the column headers) and then injecting that information to the Read CSV step and Output table step in your transformation.

Comment: Hi Ana, assuming I get the list of columns somehow by reading the file, how do I inject it to the Read CSV step?

Comment: I also found [this](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0R0/0V0/020/020) to create dynamically the transformation reading the list of columns first

Comment: Well, this is the official Pentaho Documentation for the last version (although it's been working the same for past versions, with each version they have added steps and fields supporting metadata injection: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/9.1/Products/ETL_metadata_injection

Comment: Also, in your PDI installation you have a samples directory with examples of use of common steps, in the samples/transformations/meta-inject you have exactly an example on how to use metadata injection to read a CSV file.